# Python: restrict value of the argument

Tags: python, object, instance, init

How to restrict the value of sex argument here to either male or female?

```
 class SoftwareEngineer:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex, level, salary):
        sexes=['male','female']
        if sex in sexes:
            self.sex=sex.lower()
       
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.level=level
        self.salary=salary
```

Second attempt:

```
class SoftwareEngineer:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex=['male','female'], level, salary):
        sexes=['male','female']
        if sex in sexes:
            self.sex=sex.lower()
       
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.level=level
        self.salary=salary
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to validate your parameters before creating a `SoftwareEngineer` object - by the time `__init__` is called the object has already been created.  But, if you want to do your parameter validation in the initializer then you could do something like the code below to kick it back out to the surrounding code to handle.

Example:

```
class SoftwareEngineer:
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex, level, salary):
        
        self._validate_sex(sex)
        
        self.sex = sex.lower()
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.level=level
        self.salary=salary
        
    def _validate_sex(self, sex):
        if sex.lower() not in ["male", "female"]:
            raise ValueError(f"Person's sex must specified as male or female not {sex}.")

parameters_validated = False
while not parameters_validated:
    
    # Other parameter inputs not shown for simplicity
    
    sex = input("Please enter sex of person [male, female]: ")
    
    try:
        swe = SoftwareEngineer("Fiona", 25, sex, 6, 12000)
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(exc)
        print("Please try again.")
    else:
        print("All good, thanks.")
        parameters_validated = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally you’d enforce this by raising a [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html), which is defined as:

> Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

```py
 class SoftwareEngineer:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex, level, salary):
        sexes={'male','female'}
        sex = sex.lower()
        if sex in sexes:
            self.sex = sex
        else:
            raise ValueError(“sex must be ‘male’ or ‘female’.”)
```

(Side note: I have friends who are software engineers who would be pretty annoyed at this arbitrary distinction. If you have to do this for homework, so be it. If you’re doing it for real, consider just storing whatever value gets passed in.)

Comment: There was no mention of `sorted` in the original post, so I can't speak to that. Some people are not strictly male or female biologically.

Comment: I didn’t take it personally. Think of that as advice from a friend. :-)